Cycle bake result has weird shadow
Have tried my best to fix the problem but failed.



There are shadows like dotted lines around some sharp edges. Wonder whether it caused by angle of faces changed to dramatic. Tried add bevel seems didn't fix the problem. And it makes curve face flatten. Tried add subdivision modifier. Have fixed some part of problem. But there are still many dotted line shadow. Maybe it is a basic problem that many people asked. But searched and tried some ways some thread mentioned. Still didn't solve the problem. Thanks for the help in advance.

